# Not able to add firestore to laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add firebase firestore to my laravel project and getting below error.

> Unable to create a FirestoreClient: Undefined constant Google\ApiCore\Call::PAGINATED_CALL

Below is my code

```
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'\firebase_credentials.json');   
$database = $factory->createFirestore()->database(); // On this statement
$usersRef = $database->collection('users');
$snapshot = $usersRef->documents();
foreach ($snapshot as $user) {
  $age = array("uid"=>$user['userId'],"email"=>$user['email']);
  $data[]=$age;
}
```